# Java time different from OS time

Tags: java, datetime

When I print date in Unix, it show the UTC time

```
[app@host ~]$ date
Thu Sep  6 21:16:07 UTC 2018
```

When I print the date from Java on the same machine

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("date=" + new Date());
  System.out.println("date from mills=" + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
  System.out.println(TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName());

  Instant instant = Instant.now();
  System.out.println("instant=" + instant);
  System.out.println("instant from mills=" + new Date(instant.toEpochMilli()));
}
```

It prints PST time

```
[app@host ~]$ java TimeTest
date=Thu Sep 06 14:17:09 PDT 2018
date from mills=Thu Sep 06 14:17:09 PDT 2018
Pacific Standard Time
instant=2018-09-06T21:17:09.030Z
instant from mills=Thu Sep 06 14:17:09 PDT 2018
```

How does Java get the PST timezone?

Also, the logback file rotation happens at UTC time and times printed in the log file show PST time.

Comment: …or why does Unix give you UTC? The usual case is that Java picks up its default time zone from the OS, so it’s worth noting that your Unix seems to have UTC as its time zone setting and Java Pacific Time. Each can be set independently, but there’s nothing in your question indicating that Java’s time zone setting has been set, so I cannot tell how it has happened. Examples of how to set it include a command line option and setting a system property from within Java.

Answer (score 6):

## tl;dr

Use only *java.time* classes.

Never use `Date` class.

Use UTC when logging.

```
Instant.now().toString()
```

> 2018-01-23T01:23:45.123456Z

## Details

This has been addressed many times already on Stack Overflow.

The terrible old legacy date-time classes are rife with poor design choices. Among those poor choices is the `Date::toString` method’s behavior of dynamically applying the JVM’s current default time zone while generating the string. Well-intentioned but misleading as a `java.util.Date`, like a `java.time.Instant`, represents a moment in UTC.

On September 6 of this year, 2 PM on west coast of much of North America is simultaneously 9 PM in UTC, with an offset-from-UTC of seven hours behind UTC during Daylight Saving Time (DST). Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.

### Why PDT?

Why PDT, Pacific Daylight Saving Time, in particular? Your JVM always has a current default time zone. Apparently your JVM is set to a current default of a zone such as `America/Los_Angeles` (PDT is not a real time zone).

How that default gets set depends on your JVM implementation and your settings. Usually a JVM on launch picks up on the host operating-system’s current default zone. You can pass arguments to the launch of the JVM to specify a zone rather than pick up the host OS’ default.

After launch, any code in any thread of any app within the JVM can, at any moment, change the current default time zone with a call to [`TimeZone.setDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#setDefault(java.util.TimeZone)) to affect immediately all other code in that JVM.

This means you should never rely on the current default zone for anything critical as its value is out of your control as a programmer. Always specify your desired/expected time zone explicitly. Even when you want to use the current default, make an explicit call to `ZoneId.systemDefault`.

Bonus tip: Ditto for `Locale`. Always a current default. But specify explicitly rather than rely implicitly on default.

### Using java.time

Never use the legacy date-classes. Use only *java.time* classes.

When logging, always use UTC. Render text in standard ISO 8601 format as seen in `Instant::toString`.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

If you want to view that moment in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, apply a time zone (`ZoneId`) to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: My question is more along, why was PST picked by Java. Why not EST? What environment setting is used to pick the TZ

Comment: @User1108 Added “Why PDT” section